# Python Function not returning Bool value

Tags: python, boolean, return-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does 'return self' return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272357/why-does-return-self-return-none)

I've been trying to solve Problem 55 on Project Euler (http://projecteuler.net/problem=55)
and now that I think I have the answer, I Experience a problem. I don't want a solution to the Problem 55, just on what I've done wrong.

Here's my code: (I don't think you need all of it)

```
t=0
lychrel=0
called=0

def iteratepal(n):
    global t
    global called
    called+=1
    b = int(''.join(reversed(str(n))))
    #print ("n =",n,"\nb =",b,"\nb+n =",b+n,"\n")

    if ispal(b+n) or ispal(n):
        t=0
        return False

    if t<50:
        t+=1
        iteratepal(b+n)
    else:                          # Here's the prob
        t=0                        # this block is executed (because it prints "yea")
        print("yea")               # but it doesn't return True!
        return True                # you can try it yourself (even in the interpreter)

def ispal(n):
    if n == int(''.join(reversed(str(n)))):
        return True
    return False

print(iteratepal(196))

for i in range(0,200):
    if iteratepal(i)==True:
        lychrel+=1
        print(i,"is Lychrel!")
    else:
        print(i,"is not a Lychrel!")
print(lychrel)
```

Thanks for any help, I'm really confused with this.

Comment: You never need to test `==True` in an `if` statement.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yep, forgot about that. It was False before, and after some time I changed it

Comment: In which case the normal python way to test for `False` is to use `if not something:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call the function recursively when `t < 50`, but don't do anything with the return value:

```
if t<50:
    t+=1
    iteratepal(b+n)
else:                          
    t=0                        
    print("yea")               
    return True
```

The `else:` branch is never executed then, so `None` is returned instead. You probably want to return the result of the recursive call:

```
if t<50:
    t+=1
    return iteratepal(b+n)
else:                          
    t=0                        
    print("yea")               
    return True
```

Some further tips:

- There is no need to test for `==True` in an `if` statement, the following will work just fine:

  ```
  if iteratepal(i):
  ```
- You can return the test in `def ispal(n)` is itself a boolean result, just return that without testing:

  ```
  def ispal(n):
      return n == int(''.join(reversed(str(n))))
  ```

Comment: thank you that worked, although i don't really understand the point of return , in recursion . I mean, you just call a function with new data, why whould you need to return that?

Comment: thanks for the further tips too!

Comment: @MakisRenieris, if you don't return it then it isn't recursive, it get's called once and never gets returned to the original calling function. Not only that each iteration of the recursion doesn't gets returned to the level above, which means no result ever gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the result of the recursion.  Change this

```
if t<50:
    t+=1
    iteratepal(b+n)
```

to this

```
if t<50:
    t+=1
    return iteratepal(b+n)
```

Comment: Phew, that @Martijn Pieters is *fast*!

Comment: There's a reason why he's [first this month... :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=month)

Comment: you mean: you *didn't return.  thanks for your answer